# Does anyone know how I can make the email form look tidy when it arrives using a formspree.io

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, email

I have problem with [formspree](https://formspree.io/) email response...
I managed to avoid redirecting to them site after click on submitting button.
**That looks like this**:

```js
var message = "";

$("#sendMessage").on("click", function() {
  message = $("#contactform").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    url: "//formspree.io/example@gmail.com",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      message: message
    },
    dataType: "json"
  });
  alert('Thanks for the email, we\'ll be in touch promptly.');
  return true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contactform" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Name</span><br>
      <input name="NAME" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Email</span><br>
      <input name="EMAIL" type="email" name="_replyto" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Subject</span><br>
      <input name="SUBJECT" type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">Description</span><br>
      <textarea name="DESCRIPTION" name="description" class="form-control" rows="4" cols="60" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="_gotcha" style="display:none" />
    <button id="sendMessage">Send</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

But when my mail arrives on email....
**That looks like this**:

> NAME=Johan+Doe&EMAIL=johandoe@gmail.com&SUBJECT=Some+topic&DESCRIPTION=there+some+text

**Does anyone know how I can make the email form look tidy when it arrives?**
Thanks in advance!